# Multiple div, each one with 100% height

Tags: css, html, position, height

I have a page with a lot of layers for the background (five layers) which should cover the entire page content (100% height and div).

Each layer has these properties:

```
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
min-height: 100%;
```

These properties are OK if the page content is short: the divs have an height of 100% of the window, so it's ok.

The problem is when the page is longer (look the following example). The layers have a 100% height of the browser window, not the actual content height.

That's because (I suppose) of the height:100% property. Removing it, it's fine for long pages, but not for shorter ones.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfMHm/

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `auto` instead of `100%` on height, width on all the `layer` divs.

Answer (score 0):

In the tag where your content is being displayed, you could add the CSS property `overflow`
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

You can use it to trim the excess content, or add a scrollbar.

EX.

```
.class {
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about scrolling the longer content

```
#actual_page {
        width: 990px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        height:100%;
        overflow:scroll;
        background-color: pink;
    }
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Jammycoder/cfMHm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
    `height:100%`
You can try:
    `min-height: 50%` (or whatever you need it to be).

See the cyan here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cfMHm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height:100%` from your layers CSS.